# How to fix that internal query

Tags: c#, linq

When I use the object E with group the sistem returns

> "Unknown column 't0.idEmpresa' in 'where clause'"

How do I fix this and get the necessary value from database?

**Code with ERROR:**

```
(from e in Empresas
        where e.Segmento == "comida estranha"
        select new {
            e.NomeFantasia,
            e.RazaoSocial,

            valor =    (from f in Feedbacks
                       where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
                       select f.IdFeedback).Count(),
            total =    (from f in Feedbacks
                       where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
                       join r in Respostas on f.IdFeedback equals r.IdFeedback
                       group r by r.IdFeedback into x
                       select new {
                              x.Key
                           }).Count(),

        }).ToList()
```

**Code *without* ERROR:** but this code returns wrong value from total...

```
(from e in Empresas
        where e.Segmento == "comida estranha"
        select new {
            e.NomeFantasia,
            e.RazaoSocial,

            valor =    (from f in Feedbacks
                       where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
                       select f.IdFeedback).Count(),
            total =    (from f in Feedbacks
                       //where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
                       join r in Respostas on f.IdFeedback equals r.IdFeedback
                       group r by r.IdFeedback into x
                       select new {
                              x.Key
                           }).Count(),

        }).ToList()
```

**obs.:** I'm using LINQPad to tests, but on C# also displays the error.

**obs².:** the **VALOR** is working, only the **TOTAL** is not working.

Comment: Can you please share your EF model design? Do you have entity relationships?

Comment: The `t0` in the error suggest you are actually using LINQ to SQL, and not Entity Framework. Is this the case?

Comment: The Group is producing a two dimensional array : number of keys by number of items in each key.  So what is count suppose to be?  The number of keys?

Comment: need to know the number of feedbacks answered (RESPOSTAS) of each EMPRESA

Comment: @EndersonAlmeidadaCosta LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. It's a language that runs on top of an ORM. *Don't* write LINQ as if it were SQL. Create proper entities with relations and let the ORM create the query for you. Otherwise you gain little (if anything) by using LINQ. For *reporting* queries like this one though, it may be better to just use SQL

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't assign a type to variables 'valor' and 'total' for that reason.

```
(from e in Empresas
    where e.Segmento == "comida estranha"
    select new {
        e.NomeFantasia,
        e.RazaoSocial,

       var valor =    (from f in Feedbacks
                   where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
                   select f.IdFeedback).Count(),
       var total =    (from f in Feedbacks
                   where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
                   join r in Respostas on f.IdFeedback equals r.IdFeedback
                   group r by r.IdFeedback into x
                   select new {
                          x.Key
                       }).Count(),

    }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
(from e in Empresas
where e.Segmento == "comida estranha"
select new {
    e.NomeFantasia,
    e.RazaoSocial,

   valor =    (from f in Feedbacks
               where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
               select f.IdFeedback).Count(),
   total =    (from f in Feedbacks
               where e.IdEmpresa == f.IdConsultoria || e.IdEmpresa == f.IdContratante
               join r in Respostas on f.IdFeedback equals r.IdFeedback
               select f.idFeedback).Distinct().Count()
}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so, the answer -

I believe you are trying to run this query against some database of which you have created Models for underlying tables.

Looking at the error and the LINQ query it looks like your Models are out of sync with your database table structure.

Did you changed column names after writing this query? If yes then regenerate Models and it will point you to the error in query at compile time.

Comment: Just saw you print of database. And as I said in the answer check you "Feedback" table it does not have a column name "idEmpresa". Regenerate your EF.

Comment: Well that's a different issue. I am not sure what is you are expecting as output and what it is returning. I'll suggest to create a different question, with actual and expected data, once you fix your query. And please mark this as answer if it helped.